# Date Picker (materializecss) изменить элемент на клик на который срабатывает событие .open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize-css

Суть проблемы Date Picker(materializecss) срабатывает при нажатии мышкой на input(ну типа того).

Это очень не удобно, нет возможности ввести дату вручную...

Как можно перевесить событие, например сделать иконку для запуска?

Comment: В документации ничего об этом не сказано?

Comment: нет там есть вызов события(открыть календарь), но как тогда погасить событие клика на input